# Html2PDF HTML code issue

Tags: php, html, css

Well I have been at this for hours now. I'm using HTML2PDF to generate an invoice. My program creates a temporary invoice without issue. The issue I'm having is once the program tries to create a PDF from the temp file I'm getting an error:

```
ERROR nÂ°5
File : /home/x/public_html/office/cron/invoices/php-pdf/_class/parsingHtml.class.php
Line : 218

HTML code invalid, all tags must be closed.
Status :

Array
(
    [0] => page
    [1] => table
    [2] => tr
    [3] => td
    [4] => table
    [5] => tr
    [6] => td
)
```

I understand its saying all the HTML tags have not been closed. I've validated my code many different times, many different ways and sites and all are returning valid. I had some style issues that have been fixed but I still have no luck. My html is as follows:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<title>Untitled Document</title>

<style>
<!--
body {font-family:Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;}
.center {text-align:center;}
.ltgray {color:#C5C5C5;}
.invoice {vertical-align:text-top;}
.gbk td {background-color:#EDEBEB; border:none; font-size:13px; padding-bottom:8px; padding-top:8px; padding-left:10px}
.btboader { border-bottom:thin dotted; border-color:#E4E2E2; padding-bottom:8px; padding-top:8px; padding-left:10px }
.ltgrayt {color:#969696;}
.center {align-content:center; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold;}
.db {border:thin dotted; background-color:#EDEBEB;}
.padded {padding-left:15px;}
.hr { border: 0; height: 1px; background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0)); background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0)); background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0)); background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0)); }
-->
</style>

</head>
<body>

<table style="width: 100%">
<tr>
<td class="invoice"><h2 class="ltgray">Invoice</h2> </td>
<td style="float: right">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Date:</td> <td> 03/12/2015</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Invoice #:</td> <td> 100367</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> Propery </td> <td> N/a </td>
        </tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<p></p>
<table style="width: 95%; margin: 0 auto;">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 50%"><span class="ltgray">Company Information</span><br />
        <strong>XXX</strong><br />XXXX<br />XXXX</td>
        <td style="width: 50%"><span class="ltgray">Customer Information</span><br />
         <strong>XXXX</strong><br />XXXX<br />
XXXX<br />XXXX<br />Phone: XXXX<br />Email: XXXX</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br /><p></p>
    <table style="width: 100%" class="tbl">
        <tr class="gbk">
            <td style="width: 60%"><strong>Item</strong></td>
            <td style="width: 15%"><strong>Price</strong></td>
            <td style="width: 10%"><strong>Qty</strong></td>
            <td style="width: 15%; margin: 0 auto;"> <strong>Total</strong>    </td>
        </tr>



    <tr>
        <td style="width: 60%" class="btboader">Mulch - Red</td>
        <td style="width: 15%" class="btboader">$2.50</td>
        <td style="width: 10%" class="btboader">153</td>                       
        <td style="width: 15%; margin: 0 auto;" class="btboader">$382.50</td>
    </tr>



    <tr>
    <td style="width: 60%" class="btboader">Mulch - Black</td>
    <td style="width: 15%" class="btboader">$3.50</td>
    <td style="width: 10%" class="btboader">1</td>                     
    <td style="width: 15%; margin: 0 auto;" class="btboader">$3.50</td>
    </tr>



    <tr>
    <td style="width: 60%" class="btboader">Mulch - Brown<br><small>Bagged mulch, price includes delivery - Total 2 1/2 pallets</small> </td>
        <td style="width: 15%" class="btboader">$3.50</td>
        <td style="width: 10%" class="btboader">160</td>                       
        <td style="width: 15%; margin: 0 auto;" class="btboader">$560.00</td>
    </tr>


   <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <table style="width: 100%">
            <tr>
                    <td style="width: 20%">Payment Terms:</td>
                    <td style="width: 80%">Due On Receipt</td>
        </tr>                
            <tr>
                    <td style="width: 50%">Discount(%):</td>
                    <td style="width: 50%">10.0</td>
        </tr> 
            <tr>
                    <td style="width: 50%">Past Due Amount:</td>
                    <td style="width: 50%">$0.00</td>
        </tr> 
            </table>       
         </td>
         <td colspan="2">
        <table style="width: 100%">
            <tr>
                    <td style="width: 50%" class="ltgrayt">Subtotal:</td>
                    <td style="width: 50%; float: right;">$946.00</td>
                </tr>
            <tr>
                    <td style="width: 50%" class="ltgrayt">Tax (6.5%):</td>
                    <td style="width: 50%; float: right;"> $0.00</td>
                </tr> 

            <tr>
                    <td style="width: 50%" class="ltgrayt">Discount:</td>
                    <td style="width: 50%; float: right;"> $94.60</td>
                </tr>              
            <tr>
                    <td style="width: 50%" class="ltgrayt">Past Due:</td>
                    <td style="width: 50%; float: right;"><strong> $0.00 </strong></td>
                </tr>               
            <tr>
                    <td style="width: 50%" class="ltgrayt">Total:</td>
                    <td style="width: 50%; float: right;"><strong> $851.40 </strong></td>
                </tr>               
            </table>
          </td>
       </tr>
</table>

<br /><br />
<table class="db" style="width: 80%; margin: 0 auto;">
    <tr>
        <td><strong class="padded"><small>Order Notes:</small></strong><br /><p class="padded">Thank you for your business!</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<hr class="hr">
<p class="center">XXXX, XXXX, XXXX - Phone: XXXX - Direct Cell: XXXX Email:XXXX<br />
Please make checks payable to: XXXX</p>

</body>
</html>
```

What am I missing that's causing this error? The only other thing I could think of is that HTML2PDF doesn't support something in my styling. I use HTML2PDF for another project without issue so Im not sure where I made a wrong turn.

Comment: `<hr class="hr">` isn't closed

Comment: I had it closed and when I did it gave me validation errors, just added it to the code again and still same error.

Comment: any updates on this .. i'm getting the same error :(